# Rails routing dynamic pages to friendly url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have an events website that needs to generate a new url for column name :domains that gets defined when a user creates the event in active admin i.e. http://www.re-work.co/:domains

I have event modal and events_controller and the view is events#show

In my routes file I have

```
match '/:domains' => "events#show"
  resources :events
```

My controller has this which looks like the problem but I dont know what to change it to:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
def show
  @event = Event.where(:domains => request.base_url).first

  if @event.nil?
    @event = Event.first
  end
end
```

A snippet of rake routes as all other routes are to do with admin

```
$ rake routes

         root            /                                         events#show
       events GET        /events(.:format)                         events#index
              POST       /events(.:format)                         events#create
    new_event GET        /events/new(.:format)                     events#new
   edit_event GET        /events/:id/edit(.:format)                events#edit
        event GET        /events/:id(.:format)                     events#show
              PUT        /events/:id(.:format)                     events#update
              DELETE     /events/:id(.:format)                     events#destroy
```

All these urls '/events/technology' or '/events/cities' or '/cities' or '/technology' go the same page, I am new to Rails and have read/watched rails routing tutorials but I can't figure it out. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because this line:

```
match '/:domains' => "events#show"
```

Is matching everything after "/" and pointing it to the `events#show` action. That line is not necessary (you can remove it), since:

```
  resources :events
```

Will generate all the defaults routes for the events controllers.

**Edit:**

If what you're trying to do, is capture the whatever passed as `/:domains` to be used inside of the `show` action. Then that parameters is traveling as part of the `params` hash, for instance:

```
Parameters: {"domains"=>"technology"}
```

You can access it like this `params[:domains]`. In that case, you can leave the first line as it was:

```
match '/:domains' => "events#show"
match '/events/:domains' => "events#show" # add this one

resources :events   # <- delete this one, this right now is kind of redundant for what you're trying to do
```

and change the following code:

```
  @event = Event.where(:domains => params[:domains] ).first
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have removed that line but nothing changed. I see only see the same event no matter what url I type. Have I missed something really basic?

Comment: Could you update the question with the output of the following command:  `rake routes` ? That basically tells you are the routes available in the application.

Comment: Of course, I have added it above, I think the issue is something todo with the controller and the 'first', although I have don't really know. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So in essence, if you enter the following url: `/events/technology` what the behaviour should be? Look for the first event where domain => "technology" and display that?

Comment: If I enter /events/technology i want to see the event with the domain "technology", and if I enter /events/cities I want to see the event with the domain "cities" but at the moment I only see the technology event no matter what url I enter. I don't want this 'first' control but I dont know what to replace it with if anything?

Comment: @DanMitchell Review the updated answer. With that change, you can then leave the old match: `match '/:domains' => "events#show"`, in that case then `/technology` should show the `/cities` the ones with domains cities. You could add: `match '/events/:domains' => "events#show"` to make sure that `events/technology` and `events/cities` work. I'll recommend then, to the delete the `resources events` since for now it will be redundant.

Comment: Okay so I put `match '/:domains' => "events#show"` back into the routes file and if I type `localhost:3000/cities` or `localhost:3000/technology` I get the correct event page which is perfect! I didn't want `events/...` so this is perfect! Thank you!